# のでろう in the middle of a sentence

Tags: particle-の, sentence

> 冷えているのでろうタオルを顔に当てたまま、ソイツがペコリと頭を下げる。

What exactly is のでろう here doing and nuance does it add?

Comment: It seems like a typo of のであろう. What is the source?